# Try/catch 'Call to a member function query() on null' error

Tags: php, mysql, try-catch

I have a SQL query (`$query`) that I create dynamically based on a users selections (I already perform sanitizing on user input so there is no issue of SQL injection). However sometimes the query returns a `PHP Fatal error` so I wanted to output all of the variables to a file so do some digging.

My code is:

```
try {
    $results = $db->query($query);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $all_vars = get_defined_vars();
    file_put_contents('query_problems.txt',date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . print_r($all_vars, True),FILE_APPEND);
}
```

However I still receive an error

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null

and the line it points to is where I run `$db->query($query)`.

What am I doing wrong? How do I catch this error?

Comment: $db must be defined before using it, so where is your database connection which sets $db?

Comment: PHP 8 added the nullsafe operator `?->` to prevent making method calls on a null variable. You could do `$db?->query($query);` if there is a chance `$db` doesn't get defined.

Comment: You can also append `$e->getMessage()` on `query_problems.txt`  to get exact error message

Comment: @nbk i define `$db` earlier in my code but I did not think it was necessary to add that since the code throws error on running `->query()`

Comment: @EmmaMarshall thank you for the suggestion. I wanted all the variables to be outputted so I can pinpoint the issue even further.

Comment: Check $db it is empty according to your error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're catching an [Exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php), not an [Error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) (that is being throw). If you want to catch both (exceptions and errors), you should use [Throwable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php).

```
try
{
   // Code that may throw an Exception or Error.
}
catch (Throwable $t)
{
   // Executed only in PHP 7, will not match in PHP 5
}
```

As it says in doc:

> As the Error hierarchy does not inherit from Exception, code that uses catch (Exception $e) { ... } blocks to handle uncaught exceptions in PHP 5 will find that these Errors are not caught by these blocks. Either a catch (Error $e) { ... } block or a set_exception_handler() handler is required.